# ROS-NOETIC Program works when executing by rosrun but don't work when using roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch, ros-noetic, rosrun

I have a weird problem. I've created script for catching the rospy.log and publishing it into topic and saving to files.txt. It works fine while I'm launching it by rosrun. When ,launch file was created with only this one script - it soesn't work.

Launch file code:

```
<launch>
    <!-- Uruchomienie skryptu przechwytujacego rospy.logxxx -->
    <node pkg="dhi_amr" type="rospy_log_catcher.py" name="rospy_log_catcher" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

Script code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy, datetime, os, logging
from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
from dhi_amr.msg import log_messages


class LogCatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Variables """
        """ Options """
        self.debug_enabled = True
        self.save_log_to_file = True
        self.log_file_max_size = 256
        """ Custom """
        self.log = log_messages()
        
        """ Others """
        self.received_log = Log()
        self.last_received_log = Log()
        self.create_log_directory()
        self.set_file_handling()
        try:
            """ ROS Subscriber definition """
            received_log_sub = rospy.Subscriber('rosout_agg', Log, self.received_log_callback)
            
            """ ROS Publisher definition """
            self.log_pub = rospy.Publisher('amr/log/current', log_messages, queue_size=1, latch=True)
            
        except Exception as e:
            rospy.logerr(f'Error detected in log catcher at init: {e}')
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
                rospy.logwarn(f'User stop detected in LOG CATCHER!')

    """ Callback section for log subscriber"""
    def received_log_callback(self, msg):
        self.received_log = msg
        is_new = self.is_log_new(self.received_log)
        if is_new:
            if self.save_log_to_file:
                self.create_log_line()
                self.check_file_size()
            self.create_published_topic()
            self.log_pub.publish(self.log)
            self.last_received_log == self.received_log

    """ Setting loggers and file handlers to separate files depending on log level"""
    def set_file_handling(self):
        self.debug_log_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'amr/data', 'amr_log_debug.txt')
        self.info_log_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'amr/data', 'amr_log_info.txt')
        self.warning_log_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'amr/data', 'amr_log_warning.txt')
        self.error_log_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'amr/data', 'amr_log_error.txt')
        self.fatal_log_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'amr/data', 'amr_log_fatal.txt')
        
        self.debug_logger = logging.getLogger("debug_logger")
        self.info_logger = logging.getLogger("info_logger")
        self.warning_logger = logging.getLogger("warning_logger")
        self.error_logger = logging.getLogger("error_logger")
        self.fatal_logger = logging.getLogger("fatal_logger")
        
        self.debug_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.info_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.warning_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        self.error_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        self.fatal_logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
        
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s - %(filename)s-%(funcName)s-%(lineno)d')
        
        debug_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.debug_log_file)
        info_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.info_log_file)
        warning_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.warning_log_file)
        error_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.error_log_file)
        fatal_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(self.fatal_log_file)
        
        debug_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        info_file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        warning_file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        error_file_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        fatal_file_handler.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
        
        debug_file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        info_file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        warning_file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        error_file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        fatal_file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        self.debug_logger.addHandler(debug_file_handler)
        self.info_logger.addHandler(info_file_handler)
        self.warning_logger.addHandler(warning_file_handler)
        self.error_logger.addHandler(error_file_handler)
        self.fatal_logger.addHandler(fatal_file_handler)

    """ Checking if log directiory exists and if not - creating one"""
    def create_log_directory(self):
        log_directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'log', 'data')
        if not os.path.exists(log_directory):
            os.makedirs(log_directory)

    """ Create info to publish """
    def create_published_topic(self):
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.log.date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.log.level = self.create_log_level()
        self.log.message = str(self.received_log.msg)
        if self.debug_enabled:
            self.log.node_name = self.received_log.name
            self.log.file = self.received_log.file + ' / ' + self.received_log.function
            self.log.code_line = str(self.received_log.line)
    
    """ Create info level to publish """
    def create_log_level(self):
        if self.received_log.level == 1:
            return 1
        elif self.received_log.level == 2:
            return 2
        elif self.received_log.level == 4:
            return 3
        elif self.received_log.level == 8:
            return 4
        elif self.received_log.level == 16:
            return 5

    """ Check if the log is a new log """
    def is_log_new(self, received_log):
        if received_log.header.seq != self.last_received_log.header.seq:
            self.last_received_log = received_log
            return True
        return False

    """Creating an saving log file """
    def create_log_line(self):
        log_msg = "{timestamp} - {level} - {msg} - {file}-{function}-{line} - {caller}".format(
            timestamp=self.received_log.header.stamp.secs,
            level=self.received_log.level,
            msg=self.received_log.msg,  
            file=self.received_log.file,
            function=self.received_log.function,
            line=self.received_log.line,
            caller=self.received_log.name
        )
        if self.received_log.level == 1 and self.debug_logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
            self.debug_logger.debug(log_msg)
        elif self.received_log.level == 2 and self.info_logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO):
            self.info_logger.info(log_msg)
        elif self.received_log.level == 4 and self.warning_logger.isEnabledFor(logging.WARNING):
            self.warning_logger.warning(log_msg)
        elif self.received_log.level == 8 and self.error_logger.isEnabledFor(logging.ERROR):
            self.error_logger.error(log_msg)
        elif self.received_log.level == 16 and self.fatal_logger.isEnabledFor(logging.CRITICAL):
            self.fatal_logger.critical(log_msg)

    """ Checking the file size of log, and backup last one to .last file"""
    def check_file_size(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.debug_log_file):
            file_size = os.path.getsize(self.debug_log_file)
            if file_size > self.log_file_max_size * 1024 * 1024:  
                last_log_file = self.debug_log_file + '.last'
                os.rename(self.debug_log_file, last_log_file)
                self.set_file_handling()
        if os.path.exists(self.info_log_file):
            file_size = os.path.getsize(self.info_log_file)
            if file_size > self.log_file_max_size * 1024 * 1024:  
                last_log_file = self.info_log_file + '.last'
                os.rename(self.info_log_file, last_log_file)
                self.set_file_handling()
        if os.path.exists(self.warning_log_file):
            file_size = os.path.getsize(self.warning_log_file)
            if file_size > self.log_file_max_size * 1024 * 1024:  
                last_log_file = self.warning_log_file + '.last'
                os.rename(self.warning_log_file, last_log_file)
                self.set_file_handling()
        if os.path.exists(self.error_log_file):
            file_size = os.path.getsize(self.error_log_file)
            if file_size > self.log_file_max_size * 1024 * 1024:  
                last_log_file = self.error_log_file + '.last'
                os.rename(self.error_log_file, last_log_file)
                self.set_file_handling()
        if os.path.exists(self.fatal_log_file):
            file_size = os.path.getsize(self.fatal_log_file)
            if file_size > self.log_file_max_size * 1024 * 1024:  
                last_log_file = self.fatal_log_file + '.last'
                os.rename(self.fatal_log_file, last_log_file)
                self.set_file_handling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        rospy.init_node('log_catcher', log_level=rospy.DEBUG)
        rospy.loginfo('Log catcher started')
        log_catcher = LogCatcher()
        rospy.spin()
    except Exception as e:
        rospy.logerr(f'Error detected in log catcher at main: {e}')
    finally:
        rospy.logwarn('Log catcher shuted down')
```

Maybe some good person will help me with this weird problem here :)

**EDIT**

Script works fine - only thing not working is access to files - it's not saving the logs to txt.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is how you are pointing to your directories,  namely, your use of `os.getcwd()`.

`rosrun` will run with your current working directory wherever you execute your program so if you run.

```
myuser@my-host:~$ ros2 run my_package my_node
```

from your home directory `os.getcwd()` should return "/home/myuser/"

Roslaunch however, does not execute programs from your terminal's working directory.   It so `os.getcwd()` will return the roslaunch working directory causing unexpected file paths.

You can see this for yourself by adding something like `rospy.loginfo(os.getcwd())`  to your program and see the different results running your node through roslaunch and rosrun

For more predictable behavior using roslaunch I recommend using absolute paths for your file names.